# fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"

Tags: linux, xorg, wayland, chromium-os, crostini

I'm unable to get Linux GUI apps to run on my self-built CloudReady workstation. I have a Pixelbook Go where I am able to use Linux GUI apps without a problem.

**Steps Immediately After Enabling Linux and Starting Terminal**

```
jacob@penguin:~$ sudo apt update
...
jacob@penguin:~$ sudo apt upgrade
...
jacob@penguin:~$ sudo apt install x11-apps
...
jacob@penguin:~$ xclock
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 222 requests (222 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

**Environment Information** (it's the same as on my PixelBook)

```
jacob@penguin:~$ echo $DISPLAY
:0

jacob@penguin:~$ xhost
access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
```

**System Information**

CPU:    AMD Ryzen 5900x

Motherboard:    MSI B550 Tomahawk

Storage:    980 PRO PCIe 4.0 NVMe SSD 1TB

Graphics Card:  MSI GTX 1060

CloudReady OS Version:  94.4.4 (Home Build) stable-channel 64-bit

**Thanks!**

Help (or even "this is impossible because x") would be greatly appreciated.

I also have an ongoing discussion on the r/Crostini sub-Reddit. See for what's already been discussed/tried.
https://www.reddit.com/r/Crostini/comments/rhzo64/fatal_io_error_11_resource_temporarily/

I'm stuck using only neovim until this is either solved or I give up and switch back to windows. :(